# How to improve GroovyClassLoader.loadClass performance?

Tags: java, performance, groovy, scripting, jvm

I'm using Groovy 3.0.6 in my Java project as a scripting language, allowing the user to extend the application at runtime via groovy scripting. Some users have several hundred script snippets. I'm using `GroovyClassLoader` to load them (also `CompileStatic`, but that seems to have negligible impact).

My problem is that the `parseClass` method is *extremely* slow (more than 1 second compile time per script). Here's the profiler output of a JUnit test that compiles a bunch of scripts:

[image]
The call tree. Note that I let the test run for 724 seconds and groovy is consuming 87% of the time for compilation. It strikes me as odd that `LexerATNSimulator.getReachableConfigSet` consumes so much time...

[image: Profiler Output (Hot Spots)]
The hot spots of the test run. Unsurprisingly, nothing but groovy (and java.util) here.

The source code is given to the `GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(...)` method as a regular `String`. I do have a custom code cache in place, but the compilation of a single script hits my application hard when there are hundreds of snippets to compile.

**Is there anything I can do to reduce compilation times?** They're crippling for the user experience at the moment.

Comment: no way to improve performance of parse/compile step. however you could parse/compile groovy code only once.

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578426/lock-contention-in-groovy-shell-interpreter-under-high-load/45608419#45608419

Comment: @daggett Unfortunately I have to re-compile when external things change (or when the script body itself changes). I do have a script cache in place to avoid re-compilation of the same script.

Comment: Then recompile on change and store both - original and compiled version.